# Вывод и ввод данных

Tags: delphi, mysql

Здравствуйте, не подскажете, как средствами делфи подключится к Mysql базе данных и в соответствии с требованиями выполнять различные операции? Использовал дополнительное компоненты, ругается на отсутствие библиотеки, хотя библиотека находилась в одной папке с исполняемым файлом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В группе ADO (в 7-ке) или dbGO (в 14-ой), есть компонент `ADOQuery`.
Там юзать параметр `ConnectionString`, там же есть и сам подлючальщик с выбором драйвера БД.

P.S. Как раз, то что вам посоветовал Dreadangel.
Цитирую:

> "access a MySQL database from Delphi using standard data controls without using BDE/ADO/ODBC"

Это всё есть в делфях.

Answer (score 0):

Смотри в сторону dbExpress, либо ZeosDB в конец...

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите более детально сам процесс подключения?

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/database/u/delphi_database_programming.htm
тебе в помощь